# Typo on documentation notifications: 'exampe comment'

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, notifications, typographical-error

The notification displayed in the global inbox when a Documentation example is commented on contains a typo:

[image: "exampe comment"]

According to [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestions/exampe), there is no such word and this is a typo. It should say "example" instead.

Comment: And apparently fixed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290770/inbox-typo-exampe-comment

Comment: No idea why but I only searched in meta.SO. Didn't even thought about meta.SE. My bad.

Comment: It's good to have it here as that's where people would expect to find it so no worries.